# How do I find my app's product_id for use with App Annie's API?

Tags: api, app-id, appannie

I am trying to make calls to App Annie's connect API. The `product_id` is required with every request, but I can't find it anywhere on App Annie. I have looked under "My Apps" and "App Data Details."

Sample API call for reference:

> https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/intelligence/{vertical}/{market}/app/{product_id}/history?countries={country}&feeds={feeds}&device={device}&granularity={granularity}&start_date={start_date}&end_date={end_date}

Another sample with {} filled in

> https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/intelligence/apps/ios/app/338137227/history?countries=US&feeds=downloads&device=all&granularity=daily&start_date=2016-02-01&end_date=2016-02-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find it - in the app details page scroll down to the bottom and you will see it there in very light grey (not so easy to see) - e.g. in this small example image:

<kbd>[image: screenshot here]</kbd>